# Python editor that can run python files?

Tags: python, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Are there any Python editors that can run the currently viewed file with an easy keybinding so I don't have to open the command prompt? Bonus points if it can open the Python interpreter too.

Mention any editor you know that can do this, so I have some options to choose from. Bonus points for other handy features like auto code completion, error markup, smart indent, bracket matching, line numbering etc.

Comment: This question has been asked many times.  The canonical version is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think the command prompt is the best part ;) But if you insist, try out http://pydev.org/, its the python plugin for eclipse. Its an IDE, and can have auto-completion etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't limited to open source offerings, you can try WingWare IDE:

http://wingware.com/

As far as professional WYSIWYG editors go, it is fairly mature and easy to use. It is available in three versions:

- Wing IDE Professional
- Wing IDE Personal
- Wing IDE 101

Wing IDE 101 is a free version for educators, students and hobbyists. The other two are commercial versions which offer more features than the free version. All three versions of Wing IDE run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

Plus, it meets a number of the features you requested:

```
Auto-completion, call tips, error indicators, goto-definition, find uses, source browser, code indices, and symbol lookup.
```

Also refer to this Wikipedia link for some of its features: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_IDE

Answer (score 0):

- [**Emacs**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [**vim**](http://www.vim.org/download.php)
- [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/) and its powerfull [pydev](http://pydev.org/) plugin
- [**Wingware**](http://wingware.com/)

Emacs: meta x shell-command will do the trick.

```
M-x shell-command
```

followed by

```
python foo.py
```

see  [running commands in emacs](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/shell.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) on top of Eclipse, and I'm currently building a [live-coding plugin](http://donkirkby.github.com/live-py-plugin/) that runs the code *while you type*.

Comment: The live coding plugin actually looks really interesting. I'll be checking back :)

Answer (score 0):

For smaller projects with just a few files, I am a big fan of [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/)  It is light weight, easy to use, but has many of the features of a full IDE.

If you need a full featured IDE rather than something light weight, then I second Wiz in suggesting Pydev.